# Can I call camera using Intent?

Tags: android

Can I call camera using Intent, if yes then what is the difference between intent and Camera?
cam = Camera.open(); 
I write above code but I get an error. 
How can I solve this error?

Comment: This documentation from android developers have any other details you might need: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course **yes**.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

You will get data onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) { 
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
```

**add the following feature in the *Manifest*.**

```
**<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>**
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the required permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);
```